# showing a spinner in a {{unless}} block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to show a spinner icon in my handlebars but it doesn't show up. When I look at the rails server log I can see that the icon gets served at the exact moment that the isLoaded becomes true. Should this be done in a different way?

new.handlebars.erb:

```
{{#unless content.isLoaded}}
<div>
  <%= image_tag "spinner.gif" %>
  <h3>Message</h3>  
</div>
{{else}}
 <p> something else</p>
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: why don't you use a regulare `image` tag instead of erb in this case?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I like that I can put all my images in the same place and have them served by sprockets. I'm doing the same thing in some other templates without conditionals and that seems to work fine.

Comment: So you're not planning to serve pre-compiled templates then?

Comment: Isn't the correct image included when the erb is compiled and after that the handlebars template gets compiled?

Comment: to be quite honest I'm very familiar with Rails in that regard. I didn't know it compiles erb before hbs.

Comment: It is chained. first erb gets compiled, then the hbs.